# React global state no context or redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-state-management

I recently game across the following article [State Management with React Hooks — No Redux or Context API](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/state-management-with-react-hooks-no-redux-or-context-api-8b3035ceecf8).  Since reacts inception the most talked about issue is always state management and global state.  Redux has been the popular choice and more recently the context API.  But this approach seems to be much easier, less code and more scalable.

My question is can anyone see a down side to using the this type of state management approach that I may have overlooked.  I have tweeked the code a little to support SSR and it works in Nextjs and also made it a little more friendly to use actions and the setting of the state variable.

useGlobalState.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

const effect = typeof window === 'undefined' ? useEffect : useLayoutEffect;

function setState(newState) {
    if (newState === this.state) return;
    this.state = newState;
    this.listeners.forEach((listener) => {
        listener(this.state);
    });
}

function useCustom() {
    const newListener = useState()[1];
    effect(() => {
        this.listeners.push(newListener);
        return () => {
            this.listeners = this.listeners.filter((listener) => listener !== newListener);
        };
    }, []);
    return [this.state, this.setState, this.actions];
}

function associateActions(store, actions) {
    const associatedActions = {};
    if (actions) {
        Object.keys(actions).forEach((key) => {
            if (typeof actions[key] === 'function') {
                associatedActions[key] = actions[key].bind(null, store);
            }
            if (typeof actions[key] === 'object') {
                associatedActions[key] = associateActions(store, actions[key]);
            }
        });
    }
    return associatedActions;
}

const useGlobalHook = (initialState, actions) => {
    const store = { state: initialState, listeners: [] };
    store.setState = setState.bind(store);
    store.actions = associateActions(store, actions);
    return useCustom.bind(store, React);
};

export default useGlobalHook;
```

Then set up a custom hook for a state variable can be a simple string or a object here is a simple one:

```
import useGlobalState from './useGlobalState';

const initialState = 'Hi';

// Example action for complex processes setState will be passed to component for use as well
const someAction = (store, val) => store.setState(val); 

const useValue = useGlobalState(initialState, { someAction });

export default useValue;
```

And use in component:

```
import React from 'react'
import useVal from './useVal'

export default () => {
  const [val, setVal, actions] = useVal();

  const handleClick = () => {
    setVal('New Val');
    // or use some actions
    actions.someAction('New Val');
  }

  return(
    <div>{val}</div>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
  )
}
```

This all seems like a much cleaner and easier approach and I am wondering why this isn't the go to approach for state management in react.  First you don't have to wrap everything in a provider.  Next it is extremely easy to implement and much less code is involved in the actual app.  Can anyone see a downside to using this approach. The only thing I can think of is the re rendering issue that the context api has but in small chunks this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been using a similar approach and I really like it. I actually can't believe more people don't talk about this approach. I wrote a custom hook here [React Superstore](https://github.com/SteveKanger/react-superstore). It gives you the freedom to dispatch from anywhere in the app and shallow compares to avoid unwanted re-renders. I don't see any performance issues as long as you can avoid the unwanted re-renders.

In all it is a simple concept. You basically create a function to store your state and return 2 functions. One will be a function to set the stored state and one will be a hook to be used in the react component. In the hook you grab the setState function of react on initial render with a createEffect and store it in an array. You can then use this setState function to re render your component. So when you call the dispatch function you can just loop through these setState functions and call them.

Simple example:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const createStore = (initialStore) => {
  let store = initialStore
  const listeners = new Set()

  const dispatch = (newStore) => {
    // Make it like reacts setState so if you pass in a function you can get the store value first
    store = typeof newStore === 'function' ? newStore(store) : newStore
    listeners.forEach(listener => listener(() => store))
  }

  const useStore = () => {
    const [, listener] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
      listeners.add(listener)
      return () => listeners.delete(listener)
    }, [])
    return store
  }

  return [useStore, dispatch]
}
```

Edit for React 18 using `useSyncExternalStore`:

```
import { useSyncExternalStore } from 'react'

const createStore = (initialStore) => {
  let store = initialStore
  const listeners = new Set()

  const getStore = () => store

  const dispatch = (newStore) => {
    // Make it like reacts setState so if you pass in a function you can get the store value first
    store = typeof newStore === 'function' ? newStore(store) : newStore
    listeners.forEach(listener => listener(() => store))
  }

  const subscribe = (listener) => {
    listeners.add(listener)
    return () => listeners.delete(listener)
  }

  const useStore = () => {
    return useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getStore)
  }

  return [useStore, dispatch]
}
```

Then just create a store and use in your component

```
const [useCount, setCount] = createStore(0)

const Display = () => {
  const count = useCount()
  return <div>{count}</div>
}

const addToCount = () => 
  <button onClick={ () => setCount(count => count + 1}>+</button>
```

You can also just create a file with all of your stores in it and just export them from there and use them anywhere in your app. You can use them inside or outside of react components.

```
export const [useCount, setCount] = createStore(0)
```

Then if you want to have a complex store object and you want to avoid re renders you can do a shallow compare in the dispatch function to compare the store to the new store similar to what redux does. Something like the following:

```
const shouldUpdate = (a, b) => {
  // (b) needs to be an object or you will have to do checks before looping make sure your store is an object or check it in this function
  for( let key in b ) {
    if(b[key] !== a[key]) return true
  }
  
  return false
}
```

and then in dispatch you can check this before firing the listener in your forEach loop.

```
const dispatch = (newStore) => {
  const oldStore = store
  store = typeof newStore === 'function' ? newStore(store) : newstore

  if(!shouldUpdate(oldStore, store) return

  listeners.forEach(listener => listener(() => store))
}
```

Its way less boilerplate than redux and seems to be much cleaner. The best thing is it allows you to decouple your actions from functions without attaching the actions to anything. You can simply create a store anywhere in your app and export the `useStore` and `dispatch` functions. Then you can dispatch from anywhere in your app.

Comment: This is probably the most underrated SO answer for react right now.

Comment: @JayWick ya I still can't believe more people don't use this type of approach. I updated the answer a little but I think it is way easier than importing all of these complex libraries to manage your applications state. You can essentially just store the native react setState function and fire it when you want to re render the component. Super simple. Either people just aren't aware of this method or the industry is too stuck in their ways.

Answer (score 0):

well good approach but i still see `redux` better for larger application especially when come to performance. A example using your approach,is adding The button as separated component while wrapping it with `React.memo` and firing `actions.toggle()` from the button component, but the button re render 2 times which it doesn't relay on the changed state.

so when building big apps you are always looking for performance improvement by removing unnecessary re renders but this is not the case here.

this is my analyses, thanks for your work.

here the code [showcase](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-global-state-no-redux-or-context-9m6e8?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I was using codesandbox's default react template which had React.StrictMode wrapping the app in the index.js which caused the double rendering.  If you remove it in your example in index.js it won't double render anymore.

Comment: i meant the `Button` component  doesn't relay on the state so it shouldn't  re render when state update when wrapping it with `react.memo` and this is not the case here.